# Pass data/model and route argument to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Calculate(Rankings rank, int id)
{
//do something on rank depends of id
return View(rank);
}
```

I have to pass 'rank' and 'id' from View 'Calculate' to Controller, work on data depends of id and return to this same View with updated model 'rank'?
Calculate View is a strongly-typed View with Rankings (the rank model).

I will be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you simply store the id in the Rankings object, or create a new viewmodel object that contains a property for both Rankings and id.

I tend to prefer viewmodel objects that store everything that the view needs to do its work. In other words, one object that contains Rankings and id.

That would look like this:

```
public class CalculateViewModel
{
    public Rankings Rankings { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Create that in your controller, set the properties, and pass it to the Calculate view.

The easiest approach (which I would not do) would be to use ViewData in your controller like so:

```
ViewData["id"] = id;
```